# How to implement search function to UITextView?

Tags: ios, search, uitextview, uisearchbar

I have more than 40 views with their own respective `UITexView`. I want to implement a search function that allows the user to search across the `UITextViews`. Actually, I do not even know how to implement search function for 1 `UITextView`. Therefore I do not know if it is possible at all.

I have searched the web and looked for it here but did not find what I looked for.

I appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a pretty easy (may I say obvious?) task. Just think a bit about it. What does searching in a text view mean? Well, it means getting its text and see if a particular string (the one which is searched for) is the substring of the text, and if so, where it is inside. Assuming you use a UISearchBar to hold the text to be searched for:

```
NSString *subs = searchBar.text;
NSString *wholeText = textView.text;

NSRange r = [wholeText rangeOfString:subs];
if (r.location == NSNotFound)
{
    // The term to be searched couldn't be found...
}
else
{
    // The string to be searched for is in the text view, r.location contains where exactly it is.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to find a working tutorial with this function?

Comment: @M.El-Set you can see how I implemented the text editor in my file manager app: https://github.com/H2CO3/MyFile/blob/master/src/MFFileViewerController.m

Comment: @M.El-Set and if my answer's worth an upvote or an accept, don't hesitate :)

Answer (score 0):

You can search for text in TextView like this:

```
[TextView.text rangeOfString:]
```

There's no built in controller for searching UITextView, you have to implement this functionality by yourself with above function.